# Can I use SOAPUI for concurrency testing?

Tags: soapui

I am trying to test my web service using SOAPUI (the free version). For testing concurrency, I wished to fire concurrent threads from SOAPUI onto the service. But with the options, the thread count increases gradually (even in the burst mode). The machine where SOAPUI is installed is a WinXP machine. Can I actually do the concurrency testing? If so how? Please guide me. I am waiting for your answers and help.

Comment: @John, Thanks. But can I expect the help in the near future? I am waiting for long.

Comment: I don't personally use SOAPui for this kind of testing. I write a small test program using a unit test framework. This also tests whether it's easy for your real clients to call your service.

Comment: So there is none to show me some road ahead!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a constant load just use the "simple" strategy. Select a thread count you want (e.g. 10) and choose a test delay. The delay will be randomized by the "Random" factor. This means if the random factor is 0.5 and the test delay is 10000 the tests in one thread will have a random delay from 5 seconds to 15 seconds.

So if you want a constant load you can select a delay of 0 and a specific number of threads. There will always be a fixed amount of threads using the "Simple" strategy.

Comment: If you need agents (a tool that monitors the load on the system-under-test) you may have a look at loadUI from the vendor of soapUI... Its free. However I personally haven't tried it yet, but it looks quite nice.